# Hibernate Lazy Loading - getting Listitems in List

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am currently experimenting with hibernate 5 in my java application.
I have the following problem:

I have two pojos/models:

```java
@Entity(name="Categories")
public class Category {
    @javax.persistence.Id
    private int Id;
    private String Name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "category",cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Link> links = new ArrayList<>();
    // ... getters and setters..
}
```

```java
@Entity(name="Links")
public class Link {
    @javax.persistence.Id
    private int Id;
    private String Name;
    private String Url;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="CategoryId")
    private Category category;
    // ... getters and setters..
}
```

Now i want to get all categories with links in it. My dao for that is the following:

```java
public Iterable<Category> getCategories() {
     SessionFactory factory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
     Session session = factory.getCurrentSession();
     session.getTransaction().begin();

     String hsql = "from " + Category.class.getName() + " e";

     Query<Category> query = session.createQuery(hsql);
     List<Category> cats = query.getResultList();

     cats.forEach(item -> Hibernate.initialize(item.getLinks()));

     session.getTransaction().commit();
     return cats;
    }
```

This is working but i think this is a bad solution for getting all Links from all categories. 
I already experimented with "JOIN FETCH".

For example if i use:

```java
String hsql =  "from " + Category.class.getName() + " e JOIN FETCH e.links l
```

I will get all results twice...
What is the best practise to get all Items from the list "links" from all Categories of my List?

I hope this question is not too easy but i cant find anything helpful regarding this.

Answer (score 0):

you could try using this make sure to use this inside the transcation boundary

```
List<Link> totalLinks = cats.stream().map(cat -> cat.getLinks()).
            flatMap(l -> l.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: This is also not what i want. I am searching for a possibility to make this without going through every element.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `fetch=FetchType.LAZY` you could use `fetch=FetchType.EAGER` and hibernate will resolve all the links directly on load.

Depends on the use case if you want to use this. For small data sets that is absolutely ok.

Comment: That is not what i want. When the data is growing this is not the preferred method.